# Magento2: How to add additional product info on left side of product page layout?

Tags: magento2

Magento2: How to add additional product info on the left side of product page layout? I'm using 2columns-left. I want to add some attributes info like the width & height.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have  using 2 column-left layout at product,

Then open/create **catalog_product_view.xml** at your theme `app/design/frontend/{themevendor}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Catalog/layout/`

**Add below code:**

```
<page  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.attributes" destination="sidebar" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

You have to use `<move>` tag. See how to use  tag

Comment: Thanks @Amit  i want to use a template, and in that template ill add the attribute info. how will i do that?